# A least-squares solution $\hat x$ of an inconsistent system $Ax=y$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares

I am having confusion with two statements:

A least-squares solution $\hat x$ of an inconsistent system $Ax=y$ is a solution of the normal equations $A^TA x = A^Ty$, $\hat x$ can be found by reducing $[A^TA \  A^Ty]$ to the reduced echelon form.

An inconsistent system $Ax= b$ has a unique least-squares solution $\hat x$ if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent and, in this case, $\hat x = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T b$.

I know that the second statement is true, but confused with the first one.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @littleO I want to understand why the first statement is true or false

Comment: I wonder if the question would be more clear if the second statement were omitted, in that case.

Answer (score 2):

First statement: If $A$ is not full column rank, there exists infinite solutions, which you can not solve by $(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$ because the inverse doesn't exist. Instead, you would solve the system using row echelon form.

Second statement: If $A$ is full column rank, then $(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$ is the unique solution.

So second statement is false because the system has a unique solution and therefore can not be inconsistent.

Comment: So the first statement is false and the second one is true..

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: No, both statements are true.

Comment: how come @BrianBorchers "A system of equations is called an inconsistent system of equations if there is no solution" .. In the second statement, it says inconsistent and unique solution.

Comment: It says "a unique least-squares solution."  The least-squares solution isn't a solution to $Ax=b$, but rather a vector that minimizes $\| Ax-b \|$.

Comment: yeah but a system can not be inconsistent and unique at the same time.

Comment: @BrianBorchers can you explain the first statement why it is true?

Comment: The system of equations $Ax=y$ can be inconsistent, but the system of equations $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}y$ is always consistent.  If the second system has a unique solution, then that that solution is $x=(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}y$.  However, the second might have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @BrianBorchers but can that solution  be found by reducing $[A^TA \  A^Ty]$ to the reduced echelon form?

Comment: @userly0 yes it could be found, i.e. the set of solutions.